# Trying Haskells plotList command, and nothing is being shown

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

So basically i fire up the gchi import the graphics library and then go and do this.

```
Prelude Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple> plotList [] [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unix-2.6.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.2.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-accessor-0.2.2.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-accessor-transformers-0.2.1.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package exceptions-0.6.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package temporary-1.2.0.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package utility-ht-0.0.10 ... linking ... done.
Loading package gnuplot-0.5.2.2 ... linking ... done.
```

All this stuff happens, but no image is shown? Do i have to do some sort of main function call to display or how would i go about actually seeing a picture. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Is `gnuplot` installed in your system and is on the correct path ?

Comment: i would assume so, this is the compiling process of it, but it isnt showing a graph?

Comment: No, you need to install `gnuplot`. If you are using Ubuntu, this should suffice: `sudo apt-get install gnuplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) binary installed, and not only the Haskell [gnuplot *package* from hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot). The latter doesn't really check whether you have the necessary binary installed. Depending on your platform, it simply invokes a shell command or uses a pipe and doesn't look for the return type, therefore you don't even get an error.

You can check whether you have gnuplot installed via

```
$ gnuplot --version
```

If this doesn't give you a version, you either have yet to install gnuplot, or gnuplot isn't in your path.

Comment: thank you so much for this, now everything is great.